# Overwriting a registry value using key stored in a variable

Tags: batch-file, service, registry

I am trying to overwrite a registry value for a service that keeps "crashing" when a user logs on for the first time.
After troubleshooting, I figured out that if I change the service start time from automatic to manual this fixes the issue.
I'm trying to accomplish this by a registry batch script.

The variable `BomgarService` holds the key. The reason I used *reg query* to get the key name is because the value after `bomgar-scc-*` is a random value that's different for all machines.

When I *echo* the value it prints the correct key so I know I have the right path, but I'm having trouble passing that key variable through Reg Add.

I have tried passing the variable using the following attempts which have all failed.

- `%BomgarService%`
- `"\"%%BomgarService%%\""`
- `^"^%BomgarService^%^"`

**Here is my code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal

::Get the path of the bomgar service and set it to our variable 
"BomgarService"
set "BomgarService=reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services /K /F 
bomgar-scc /S | find "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE""

%BomgarService%

REG ADD ^"^%BomgarService^%^" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f

pause
```

**The output:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bomgar-scc-5C4F6978
ERROR: Invalid key name.
Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is you're trying to escape the quotes and string. You need to quote the string instead. Bellow is the example I tested this with.

```
Set "Test=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\NewKey"

reg.exe add "%Test%" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
```

**Output:**

```
The operation completed successfully.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

**EDIT:**

After reexamining your script, it appears you are trying to set an actual command to a string. You can use a for loop to extract the result of this command from bellow.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services /K /F bomgar-scc /S^| find /V "End of search"') do (
    Set "BomgarService=%%A"
)

echo %BomgarService%
```

Keep in mind I have not tested your reg command and and do not know the result of it. If It does what you want already, it should output the result of the following command and set the result as the string. Please play-around with it to make sure it's displaying what you want before adding the reg.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and still get the same error output.

    REG ADD "%BomgarService%" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f

Also keep in mind my variable that has the key is the output of the reg query. I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: @Koobah84 Yeah... After looking at your script I see your issue. You are setting a command as the string. I will edit my script with a possible solution.

Comment: I tried the latest code, but the cmd window just flashes. I opened up a seperate cmd window and directed it to the path of the batch script and tried running it that way and got this error "| was unexpected at this time." Then I tried using this
 "for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services /K /F bomgar-scc /S ^| find "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"') do (
    Set "BomgarService=%%A"
)" 

After that I get this error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: @Koobah84 Yeah, the `|` needs to be escaped. Also it looks like `| find "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"` is not needed at all as you're already searching the HKLM. This might be why you are getting no results. Make sure when you type `reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services /K /F bomgar-scc /S` into a cmd it displays the key you're looking for. You can also put your `reg.exe add "%Test%" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f` into the for loop to process each result found.

Comment: I got a little bit further. This command prints out the key just like I want.
"FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services /k /s /f bomgar-scc') DO (Echo %%A | findstr /C:"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")"

However, still having trouble setting it to a variable. :S

Also, in response to your question, when I type in "reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services /K /F bomgar-scc /S" the key does show, but it has additional lines. It prints this out:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bomgar-scc-5C4F6978
End of search: 1 match(es) found.

Comment: The updated code in your script returns this: "End of search: 1 match(es) found." I need the line above that, that's why I included the find to return the whole path of the reg key. This is the part I'm stuck on.

Comment: Yeah you need to add `| find /V "End of search"` to exclude that result. Remember you have to escape the `|` with a `^`.